# Can't subscribe to spring.io newsletter

Tags: spring, email, newsletter

I wanna subscribe to the spring.io newsletter, but it doesn't work.
I have tried 2 mail accounts and submitted many support forms on VMware but nobody answers. How can I connect to spring.io support directly??

I have subscribed https://spring.io/ newsletter, but I don't receive any news. Please, provide me the mail of spring.io support to connect and solve this issue

Comment: I doubt Stackoverflow is an appropriate forum for this question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community I have subscribed https://spring.io/ newsletter, but I don't receive any news. Please, provide me the mail of spring.io support to connect and solve this issue